# LibGDX - Collisions error (player with rectangles)

Tags: java, libgdx

I think that's a simple error, but I've crashed my mind thinking about it and I can't do it.
I don't know why when I jump with the player and collides with another rectangle (platform) the player appears above it.

```
        for(RectangleMapObject rectangleObject : map.getLayers().get("platform").getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)){

        Rectangle rectangle = rectangleObject.getRectangle();

        float x = rectangle.x;
        float y = rectangle.y;
        float width = rectangle.width;
        float height = rectangle.height;

        shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height);

        //TODO: Finish tile's physics
        if(Intersector.overlaps(rectangle, nihanRect)) {
            if (velocity.y > 0) {
                nihan.getVelocity().y = 0;
                nihan.getPosition().y = y - height - Constants.NIHAN_HEIGHT - 10;


                nihan.setCollisions(false);
                nihan.setAvailableJump(false);
            } else {
                nihan.getPosition().y = y + height - 0.5f;
                nihan.setCollisions(true);

                nihan.setAvailableJump(true);

                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Z)){
                    nihan.getPosition().y = y + height;
                }
            }
            nihan.getVelocity().y = 0;

            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Collision produced!");




        }else{
            nihan.setCollisions(false);

        }}
```

Sorry if my english is bad, I'm a spanish speaker.
Greetings!

[When the player is standing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAtZv.png) -->
[After jumping the player appears in the top of the platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDFB7.png)

Comment: can you please post a picture showing what do you mean by `the player appears above it.`

Comment: What value is `Constants.NIHAN_HEIGHT`? Appears that it is a negative number and thus pushing the player up.

Comment: @bestwishes I can't do it know sorry..., but later yes

Comment: @Madmenyo No, it's a positive number

Comment: @Runforyourlife well, then you are pushing your sprite up somewhere else since the code you currently showing just pushes it down on collision.

Comment: @bestwishes Now I have added images. Sorry for the late!

Comment: Now I had resolved the problem. Thank you to all anyways! ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed variable "velocity.y" to "nihan.getVelocity.y"